# v.net modules QGIS 2.14 OSX

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, osx

the .net modules have been added to the toolbox for 2.14 but I can't see them running under OSX (10.11.1) using kyngchaos. I can see other Grass 7 tools but not the v.net ones. 
I know I can run these by running grass inside QGIS but that is very fiddly.

Any ideas how to fix?